# Double Trouble (Double For Loops) [String Task]

Tags: python, string, for-loop

So I have a string task where I'm supposed to remove the vowels from the input string.

```
case = list(input().lower()) 
vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u","y"]

for i in case:
    for k in vowels:
        if i == k:
            ind = case.index(i)
            del case[ind]
print(case)
```

Say my input is the word

> 'Tour'

instead of deleting vowels 'o' 'u' and printing

> ['t','r']

it prints

> ['t','u','r']

instead.

However, if I run the for statement separately through jupyter notebook, it can give me ['t','r'] but it's not supposed to run twice.

Any advice please.

Comment: Do not modify a list you are iterating over... construct a new list (you can look into list comprehensions if you want to use python's more powerful constructs). (And since when is `y` a vowel :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing the list of the outer for loop. E. g. your word is "Tour". In your for loop `i` is set to the first letter of `case`. It's `T` and nothing happens. `i` is set to the second letter, which is vowel `o`. You remove it and the second letter is now `u`. `i` is set to the third letter `r` and nothing happens. Your program finishes.

To avoid this problem use a second list for the result and do not change the list you are iterating over.

```
case = list(input().lower()) 
vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
result = ''

for i in case:
    if i not in vowels:
        result += i
print(result)
```

Comment: OK, so I understand why the 'u' was not deleted because it replaced the 'o's' index position and therefore skipped by the computer.